# Override target in Ant build script to copy a jar file to libs directory

Tags: java, android, code-organization, project-organization

I currently have a project in a directory named `bbct`. This contains subdirectories `swing`, with the Swing version, `android` with the Android version, and `common` with code that (possibly) is shared between the two. The `swing` and `common` subdirectories are organized as NetBeans projects with `nbproject`, `src`, `build`, and `dist` subdirectories. The `android` subdirectory is an Android SDK project with `src`, `res`, and `gen` subsdirectories.

Now I need to make sure that, when I build my Android project, the JAR file in `common` is built via an Ant script. I believe I can add the necessary information to my android project's Ant script to do this. (I haven't tried yet.) I also need to access the classes in the generated `bbct-common.jar` from my Android project and included these classes, or the JAR file itself, in the APK file generated for my Android app. How do I do this last part?

**Update:**

From [Ant build scripts, antcall, dependencies, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790/ant-build-scripts-antcall-dependencies-etc), I learned that I can use the `<ant>` task to make sure my `bbct-common.jar` file is up-to-date. I also learned from [How do I reference external jar files in a common directory (not libs) to build android project using ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312478/how-do-i-reference-external-jar-files-in-a-common-directory-not-libs-to-build), [How to specify lib folder for JARs when using Android-generated ant build file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611105/how-to-specify-lib-folder-for-jars-when-using-android-generated-ant-build-file), and [How to build an android app with external libraries using ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465285/how-to-build-an-android-app-with-external-libraries-using-ant) that I need to copy the JAR file to `bbct/android/libs`. Now my question is, what target do I override in my `bbct/android/build.xml` file to do this? In particular, I would like to override a single target so that both the `debug` and `release` builds call it. Is there a common dependency to these two targets where it is common to do these kinds of tasks?